# kohana: a file containing strings?

Tags: php, kohana

I am new to kohana and not an expert with php
excuse me if this is a duplicate but I don't even know the correct terms to perform a search for this.

I want to have a file where I can have a list of key-value thing and I want these to be accessible from templates and/or controllers.

in order to do this:
1) what do I need to do to create such a file? which folder do I put it in? what will make it accessible by template files and controllers?

2) shall I declare each key as a $string and assign a value i.e. $example = "example value"; or is there a better way?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want to store some data in a config file. You can learn how to use config files here: http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/files/config

Config data can be read mostly anywhere in your application using the global Kohana class, eg: `Kohana::$config->load('myconf');` but generally you don't want to access globals in your views, but rather pass in data to your views, eg:

```php
class Controller_Contact extends Controller {

        public function action_index()
        {    
                $names = Kohana::$config->load('names');

                $view = View::factory('people')
                        ->set('names', $names);

                $this->response->body($view);
        }
}
```